# Error in Nifi ExecuteProcess Processor - Host Key Verification Failed

Tags: ssh, apache-nifi

I am trying to do a POC using ExecuteProcess to start a .sh file on a remote server. Right now I am just trying to move a file on remote server from one location to another using Nifi. But I am getting an error (Host Key Verification Failed) on the Nifi Processor. I am able to do the same via terminal on host machine (on which Nifi is installed and running). What could be the issue here? I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/90523/executing-shellpython-script-to-a-remote-machine-i.html). Help!

```
ssh -i user@hostname 'mv ~/folder1/test.txt ~/folder2/'  <-- I am able to do this successfully on terminal.
```

**ExecuteProcess Properties :**

```
Command: ssh 
Command Arguments: -i "~/.ssh" user@hostname 'mv ~/folder1/test.txt ~/folder2/' 
Batch Duration : No value set 
Redirect Error Stream : false 
Working Directory : No value set 
Argument Delimiter : No value set
```

Comment: that's a standard error from ssh command. i think the problem appears because the user under which nifi is running does not have hostname verified. so, run your ssh command under the same user as nifi is running. or you can try to add `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no` parameter to ssh command (not sure it'll work)

Comment: @daggett thanks... I think so too. I guess I have to figure out some other way to schedule my operations. Admins won't allow nifi user's ssh auth key to be added to the remote host.. :/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments adding `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no` works and you might want to add the remote host to the list of known hosts as NiFi might not have the permission to do so